# COBOL74 - Running COMPUTING codes

Tags: cobol

Hi stackoverflow people and I'm happy to be in here. I'm a graduating student with a very weak background in almost all of my programming subjects since 2nd year.

I have this assignment that's related to computing in COBOL and I couldn't make my program to run although no errors have been found.

Write a program to print out information for each employee. The problem
definition is shown below:
Notes:

- a. Each employee’s salary is to be increased by 7%
- b. The union dues    have increased by 4%
- c. The insurance has increased by 3% d. The    amounts for dues and
  insurance are to be printed with actual decimal    points.

Field/Field size/Type/Number of Decimal points

- EMPLOYEE NO. - SIZE 5 - ALPHANUMERIC
- EMPLOYEE NAME - SIZE 20 - ALPHANUMERIC
- UNUSED - SIZE 4 - ALPHANUMERIC
- ANNUAL SALARY - SIZE 6 - NUMERIC - WITH 0 DECIMAL POINTS
- UNUSED - SIZE 13 - ALPHANUMERIC
- UNION DUES - SIZE 5 - NUMERIC - WITH 2 DECIMAL POINTS
- INSURANCE - SIZE 5 - NUMERIC - WITH 2 DECIMAL POINTS
- UNUSED - SIZE 22 - ALPHANUMERIC

Hope you can help me! :( This is my code btw (assuming that I have a .txtfile)

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. EXP2.
   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
   INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
   FILE-CONTROL.
        SELECT IN-EMP-FILE ASSIGN TO DISK
        ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
        SELECT OUT-PAYROLL-FILE ASSIGN TO DISK
        ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.

   DATA DIVISION.
   FILE SECTION.

   FD IN-EMP-FILE
       LABEL RECORDS ARE STANDARD
       RECORD CONTAINS 80 CHARACTERS
       VALUE OF FILE-ID IS "INPUTEMP.TXT"
       DATA RECORD IS IN-EMP-REC.
   01 IN-EMP-REC.
       05 IN-EMP-NUM        PIC X(5).
       05 IN-EMP-NAME       PIC X(20).
       05 UN1               PIC X(4).
       05 IN-SAL            PIC 9(6).
       05 UN2               PIC X(13).
       05 IN-UNI            PIC 9(5).
       05 IN-INS            PIC 9(5).
       05 UN3               PIC X(22).


   FD OUT-PAYROLL-FILE
       LABEL RECORDS ARE STANDARD
       RECORD CONTAINS 400 CHARACTERS
       VALUE OF FILE-ID IS "PAYROLL.TXT"
       DATA RECORD IS PRINT-REC.

   01 PRINT-REC PIC X(400).    

   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.

   01 WS-WORK-AREAS.
       05 ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS PIC X(3) VALUE 'YES'.
       05 U PIC 9(5)v99.
       05 I PIC 9(5)v99.
       05 WS-DATE.
            10 WS-YEAR PIC 99.
            10 WS-MONTH PIC 99.
            10 WS-DAY PIC 99.

   01 OUT-HDR1.
       05 FILLER PIC X(30)
       VALUE 'PAYROLL'.
       05 FILLER PIC X(6)
       VALUE 'DATE'.
       05 OUT-MONTH PIC XX.
       05 FILLER PIC X VALUE '/'.
       05 OUT-DAY PIC XX.
       05 FILLER PIC X VALUE '/'.
       05 OUT-YEAR PIC XX.



   01 OUT-HDR2.
       05 FILLER PIC X(30).
       05 FILLER PIC X(30)
       VALUE 'PAYROLL FILE'.

   01 OUT-HDR3.

       05 FILLER PIC X(15)
       VALUE 'ACCT NO.'.
       05 FILLER PIC X(30)
       VALUE 'NAME OF EMPLOYEE'.
       05 FILLER PIC X(19)
       VALUE 'OLD SALARY'.
       05 FILLER PIC X(15)
       VALUE 'NEW SALARY'.
       05 FILLER PIC X(10)
       VALUE 'OLD DUES'.
       05 FILLER PIC X(10)
       VALUE 'NEW DUES'.
       05 FILLER PIC X(20)
       VALUE 'OLD INSUR'.
       05 FILLER PIC X(10)
       VALUE 'NEW INSUR'.



   01 OUT-PAYROLL-REC.    
       05 OUT-EMP-NUM       PIC X(5).
       05 FILLER            PIC X(10).
       05 OUT-EMP-NAME      PIC X(20).
       05 FILLER            PIC X(4).
       05 OUT-SAL           PIC Z(6).
       05 FILLER            PIC X(20).
       05 OUT-NSAL          PIC Z(6).
       05 FILLER            PIC X(20).
       05 OUT-UNI           PIC Z(5).
       05 FILLER            PIC X(10).
       05 OUT-NUNI          PIC Z(5).99.
       05 FILLER            PIC X(10).
       05 OUT-INS           PIC Z(5).
       05 FILLER            PIC X(15).
       05 OUT-NINS          PIC Z(5).99.
       05 FILLER            PIC X(20).


   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   100-MAIN-MODULE.
       OPEN INPUT IN-EMP-FILE 
       OUTPUT OUT-PAYROLL-FILE.



       ACCEPT WS-DATE FROM DATE.
       MOVE WS-MONTH TO OUT-MONTH.
       MOVE WS-DAY TO OUT-DAY.
       MOVE WS-YEAR TO OUT-YEAR.

       WRITE PRINT-REC FROM OUT-HDR1.
       WRITE PRINT-REC FROM OUT-HDR2.
       WRITE PRINT-REC FROM OUT-HDR3.

       READ IN-EMP-FILE
       AT END MOVE 'NO' TO ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS.
       PERFORM 200-CALC-RTN UNTIL ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS = 'NO'.
       CLOSE IN-EMP-FILE
       CLOSE OUT-PAYROLL-FILE.

        STOP RUN.

   200-CALC-RTN.

       MOVE IN-EMP-NUM TO OUT-EMP-NUM.
       MOVE IN-EMP-NAME TO OUT-EMP-NAME.
       MOVE IN-SAL TO OUT-SAL.
       COMPUTE IN-SAL = IN-SAL + IN-SAL * .07. 
       MOVE IN-SAL TO OUT-NSAL.
       MOVE IN-UNI TO OUT-UNI.
       COMPUTE U = IN-UNI + (IN-UNI * .04).
       MOVE U TO OUT-NUNI.
       MOVE IN-INS TO OUT-INS.
       COMPUTE I = IN-INS + IN-INS * .03.
       MOVE I TO OUT-NINS.




       WRITE PRINT-REC FROM OUT-PAYROLL-REC.

       READ IN-EMP-FILE
       AT END MOVE 'NO' TO ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS.
```

Comment: What is your question? What difficulty are you having?

Answer (score 3):

First thing is, you never assume you have a txtfile, or any other, you check. For every IO operation you should check the file-status code. This means amending the SELECT statements to included the FILE STATUS definition.

Using 88-levels for conditions with literals is clearer and more easily maintainable, and less prone to typos.

You are using a "priming read" (reading file before going into the loop which reads the rest of the file, if any) which is good, but you could put the READ into a paragraph/SECTION and PERFORM it, so you don't have duplicated code and it can have a nice name.

You state COBOL-74, so you can't remove the full-stops/periods at the end of each line, so we'll leave that.

You should make your data-names meaningful and descriptive. Even NewSalary = OldSalary + ( OldSalary * SalaryHike ) is much clearer than you have.

Your fields with printable decimal places are the wrong size. Your definition occupies eight bytes and you are supposed to use five. Since you have two decimal digits and a decimal place and you need all of that, you should be able to work out what to do.

In your COMPUTEs you have a mixture of parenthesis/non-parenthesis. Parenthesise everything. Then your intent is clear to the next person looking at your program (in this case, the person grading your work).

If you are reporting, it may not be enough to write records to a file. You perhaps should have new headings for each new page.

You make no attempt to "round" the calculated results, you just allow the low-order decimal to be truncated. You should look up how to use ROUNDED.

You have 200-CALC-RTN, but it is already reading the file. Make the name a better fit.

As has been commented, we need to know what your actual problem is.